# How do you get elements from list of tuples in SML?

Tags: sml

I've just started learning SML and now I wonder how you get elements from a list of tuples? Say that I have the list [(#"D", 7), (#"E", 5), (#"M", 1), (#"N", 6), (#"O", 0),
(#"R", 8), (#"S", 9), (#"Y", 2)] and just want the integers so I can add them together like 7 + 5 + 1 + 6 + 0 + 8 + 9 + 2. Is this possible, and if so, how can it be done?

Comment: If you are a beginner in the language, it would probably be best to try and create a recursive function which sums up the integer components of the tuples. It's not much work, and this way you will gain a lot of insight into ML.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do, but I can't get it to work. But thanks for the tip, I guess I'll get it right eventually!

Comment: Edit your post to let us know what you already tried, this way you'll get more specific suggestions. - Oh, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following gets the list containing all the second elements of the tuples - that is, the integers in your example list.

```
fun getSeconds []          = []
  | getSeconds ((_,x)::xs) = x :: getSeconds xs
```

If you want to add them as you go along:

```
fun sumSeconds []          = 0
  | sumSeconds ((_,x)::xs) = x + sumSeconds xs
```